# Alter contextual links

Tags: 8, navigation

I'm trying to alter custom blocks contextual menu.
In particular I need to remove "Configure block" and "Delete".
Is there any way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Do you try [hook_contextual_links_view_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!contextual!contextual.api.php/function/hook_contextual_links_view_alter/8.2.x)

Comment: @Jonh yes, but nothing :/

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to alter contextual links is to use [`hook_contextual_links_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_contextual_links_alter).

In your case, it should look something like:

```php
function my_module_contextual_links_alter(array &$links, $group, array $route_parameters) {
  if ($group === 'block') {
    // Hide Configure Block option.
    unset($links['entity.block.edit_form']);
  }
}
```

The contextual links are heavily cached in the browser, therefore you need to make sure that the browser session cache is cleared - `window.sessionStorage.clear();` - [source](https://api.drupal.org/comment/63910#comment-63910).

Comment: Also note that this only works in modules; **not** themes.

Comment: The array key for _Configure Block_ is ```$links['block_configure']```

Answer (score -1):

You can by adding this to your theme's css file.

**style.css**

```
.block-configure,
.block-contentblock-delete { 
  display: none; 
}
```

Comment: Real Drupal way... hack it!